# What is the best way to check control state on load via Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer

I have a page that is checking the state of controls in a jQuery load function.

This was working perfectly but have now noticed that it doesn't in IE.

```
$g(window).load(function() {
   var one = $find("<%= rb1.ClientID%>");
   var two = $find("<%= rb2.ClientID%>");
     alert(1);
        if (one.get_checked()) {      
            alert(2);
            $g('[id$="div1"]').hide();
            $g('[id$="div2"]').show();                    
        }
        else if (two.get_checked()) {   
            alert(3);
            $g('[id$="div1"]').hide();
            $g('[id$="div2"]').show();                
        }     
});
```

In IE the contol state checks are never hit (i.e. I never see an alert for 2 or 3 but do see the alert for 1)

In other browsers I don't have any problems and all works as expected. Is there a better way for me to implement the above.

Thanks.

Comment: It's the client api for the Telerik .Net controls. I suppose it may be them causing the issue. I'll look into that.

Comment: look at the first line of code: $g(window)  . what is the 'g' doing there? the right is $(window) . there is also no method $find, the right is $.find .  don't know how worked on other browsers, your syntax is incorrect

Comment: $g is my jQuery call, I use the g for compatibility issues. $find is part of the Telerik control suite client side api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is a problem with the Telerik controls. In order to get around the issue I am calling a function on the radio button controls OnClientLoad command rather than the window.onload

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery for check the checked status.

```
isOneChecked = one.is(':checked');
```

or use javascript.

```
isOneChecked = one[0].checked;
```